# Countdown with RXJava and increase Button

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I am working on a countdown for an Android application.
So far the countdown just counts from 10 to 1 and it works fine.

```
 Observable observable = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .take(10) // up to 10 items
            .map(new Function<Long, Long>() {
                @Override
                public Long apply(Long v) throws Exception {
                    return 10 - v;
                }
            }); // shift it to 10 .. 1
```

I have multiple subscriptons like the following:

```
//subscription 1
    observable.subscribe(new Consumer<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Long countdown) throws Exception {
                    Log.e(TAG,"countdown: "+countdown);
                }
            });

    //subscription 2
    observable.subscribe(new Observer() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Object value) {
            //whatever
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.d(TAG,"completed");
        }
    });
```

First of all: Is this a good usecase? Am I doing it right?

My problem now is, that I would like to be able to **increase the countdown any time the user presses a button.**
Consequently I can't use my current Observable, but I dont know how to implement it.
Can anybody help? :)

Comment: I can't see why you need 2 subscriber. Put your Consumer code into the subscription2's onNext().

Comment: And I suppose interval is a hot observable. You need a replay().autoConnect() if you want 2 subscriber get the same values.

Comment: @PhoenixWang I use not only 2, but 4 subscriber because they are on different places. The observable is in a service, 1 subscriber is the countdown in the UI, 1 subscriber updates a button as soon as the countdown finished, 1 subscriber starts another service .. and so on. I thought thats what I use this pattern for?

Comment: @PhoenixWang oh and yes you are absolutely right .. its hot and therefor my idea is wrong anyway

Comment: Hi!
First be aware that each subscriber will get it's own interval. That it, countdown for each will start independently when subscription is done. You can read more about on the internet searching for "Hot and cold Observables".

Implementation will depend on your Service API. Is it something like interface CountdownService { void start(); void addMoreTime(long millis), Observable<Long> finishedAfter();} ?

Comment: @YuriyKulikov Hey, what I want to achieve is just 1 countdown that publishes to all subscribers. .publish().autoConnect() does what I want (except that I dont get an onCompleted if I subscribe after the observable completed). Yes my interface looks that way :)

Comment: @simmerl For clarify , from what i test the interval will return you a cold observable but for each subscriber but it will recount from 0.You do share the intervalObservable instance for each subscriber,but inside the observable, every subscribe has their own counter. You can publish the Observable to make everyone get the same value.

Comment: Hi, I implemented: https://gitlab.com/HansWurst315/RxJavaExamples

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
    private BehaviorSubject<Long> timer = BehaviorSubject.create();

... 
    timer
        .compose(bindToLifecycle()) // unsubscribe when view closed
        .switchMap(time -> Observable.intervalRange(0, time, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .map(t -> time - t))  // restart timer always when timeLeft have new value
        .compose(bindToLifecycle()) // unsubscribe when view closed
        .doOnNext(this::updateTimerView) 
        .subscribe();

...
    onButtonClick(){
        timer.onNext(10);
    }
```

I use swithMap to generate new timer observable every time, that timer value is updated.

But, in this decision you need to be careful with the unsubscription.